# Using VersionOne's RESTful API to re-rank stories

Tags: api, rest, versionone

How do I change the rank order of Stories through VersionOne's RESTful API?

Answer (score 5):

If you do a data query 
`http://YourVersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Order,ID&sort=Order`, 

you will get the natural creation order of your stories in Descending order.

There are two operations: 1) insert before some story and 2)insert after some story.

**GIVEN**

I) Assume that I am examining a list of Stories sorted in Descending order. In this context, the use of the word "before" implies a smaller Order number.

II) Assume a fragmented list of of stories in the form of [...-(x+c),-x, x+c...] where there is no guarantee of consecutive order numbers in this list.

III) Negative Order numbers may be present

IV) I am looking at the descending order as the basis of this explanation and "smaller Order number is better" is arbitrary. Ascending frame of 
reference is equally valid.

**Example 1: Insert before**

I want to insert my Story:9999 before my Story:1234.  After doing a query, I discover that

*Story:9999 has an Order of 454

Story:1234 has an Order of 2048*

Here is what I need to perform this order change via REST in VersionOne

VersionOne URL: `https://myVersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Story/1234`

Method: POST

Payload: `<Asset>
<Attribute name="Order" act="set">454+</Attribute>
</Asset>`

The end result is
 
*Story:1234  has an **Order < Story:9999**.*

The reason why i didn't give you the exact Order number of each is because I have noticed a couple of things

a) The operation could force Story:1234 to Hijack the original Order (454) and bump the Story:9999 to the next available slot and bump its inhabitant (Ala insertion sort in a fixed array scenario)

or

b) The operation could insert assign Story1234 an unused Order number that meets the condition of unusedOrderNum < Story:9999.Order.  This allows Story:9999 to keep its same order number.
  *NOTE: These empty slots come from deletions.

**Example 2: Insert after**

I want to insert my Story:9999 after my Story:1234.  AFter doing a query, I discover that

*Story:9999 has an Order of 454

Story:1234 has an Order of 2048*

Here is what I need to perform this order change via REST in VersionOne

VersionOne URL: `https://myVersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Story/1234`

Method: POST

Payload: 
    `<Asset>
    <Attribute name="Order" act="set">454-</Attribute>
    </Asset>`

The end result is
*Story:9999 has an Order of 454

Story:1234 has an order of 453*

In summary, OrderNum+ inserts before some story s and OrderNum- appends after some story s.

Comment: Still Works 4 years later - Thanks!